# <b:form> Tag Library supports namespace: http://bootsfaces.net/ui, but no tag was defined for name: form

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I am writing a code using JSF + Bootsfaces + Xhtml. When I try to include `<b:form href="#">` in my code, I get the following error:

> javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException:
>   /Internal_Pages/GoogleSearch.xhtml @43,21  Tag Library
>   supports namespace: http://bootsfaces.net/ui, but no tag was defined
>   for name: form

On Bootsfaces' website, the usage is shown like this as It doesn't seem lot different than mine;

```
<b:form>
  <b:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{settingsBean.checkbox1}" caption="checkbox 1" label="Please decide" />
</b:form>
```

Can someone explain how to can solve it please? By the way tags like `<b:inputText` works without giving error.

Comment: Generally it means that you try to use a component that doesn't exist (in your case form). What is the bootfaces version you are using?

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help. I see my bootsfaces version as 0.6.0 in my pom.xml file.

Comment: Always always always post version info and always always always try latest version info before posting

Comment: Will make sure to do that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form component exists since 1.0, so you have to update the version or you can not use it.

Comment: I have updated the primefaces library to v1.0.0 on maven and it is absolutely working! Thank you.